# How could i make this python program also write out file locations of the searchword?

Tags: python

So right now my code only writes out if the given searchword is in the folder or not. But I would like it to also write out the filenames where the given word exists. How would it be done?

```
import os
folder = input("Enter the search path to the folder: ")
search_word = input("Enter the search word: ")

os.chdir(folder)

def read_files(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            contents = file.read().lower()
            return contents
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File couldn't be found!")
    except IOError:
        print("Couldn't read from file")
    except:
        print("An error has occurred")

def write_searches():
    try:
        with open("ord.txt", 'w') as file:
            file.write(folder+ ": " + search_word +"\n")
            if search_word not in read_files(file_path):
                file.write("The word isn't in the folder!")  
            else:
                file.write("The word is in the file!")
    except Exception:
        print("Couldn't write to file!")  
  
print("These are the following files that have been searched: ")
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = f"{folder}\{file}"
        print("\t",file_path)
  
        read_files(file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_searches()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
file.write("The word is in the file!")
```

to:

```
file.write(f"The word is in the file {file_path}!")
```

Note that as written, `write_searches` doesn't actually iterate over multiple files; you're doing that in a different loop.  I think this might be more along the lines of what you're trying to do:

```
import os


def search_file(file_path: str, search_word: str) -> bool:
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            contents = file.read().lower()
            return search_word.lower() in contents
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to read from {file_path}: {e}")
        return False


def write_searches() -> None:
    folder = input("Enter the search path to the folder: ")
    search_word = input("Enter the search word: ")
    os.chdir(folder)
    try:
        with open("ord.txt", 'w') as output:
            output.write(f"{folder}: {search_word}\n")
            print("These are the following files that have been searched: ")
            for file in os.listdir():
                if not file.endswith(".txt"):
                    continue
                file_path = os.path.join(folder, file)
                if search_file(file_path, search_word):
                    output.write(f"The word is in {file}!\n")
                else:
                    output.write(f"The word isn't in {file}!\n")
                print("\t", file_path)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Couldn't write to file! {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_searches()
```

Comment: If I change my code to what you suggested, it only writes out one file that contains the word, when I know the folder has several files containing the word... Should I make a loop of some sort?

Comment: Yes, you should be calling `write_searches` in the loop where you iterate over the paths.  You also probably want to pass `file_path` as an argument to `write_searches` instead of having it pull it from the caller's scope; less chance for confusion.

Comment: Actually, a better approach now that I look more closely at the code is probably to just move all the global-scoped code into `write_searches`.